# Calling toString on objects

Tags: java, arrays, oop, tostring

I have a class `Game` that has a `toString` method.

I would like to iterate through an array using a nested for loop and then for each `Tile` element in the specified index of this array, print out a specific string based on that `Tile`'s attributes which is inside the `toString` method that I have written in the `Tile` class.

If this is the appropriate logic for this, how can I implement this? I am unable to properly match parameters between the two `toString` methods.

```
public String toString(tileArr){
    for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++){      
        for(int j = 0; j < columns; j++){ 
            tileArr[i][j].toString(t);
        }   
        System.out.print("\n");
    }
    return "";
}
```

Comment: Why are you doing this rather than call/create appropriate methods that return the values directly?

Comment: @Richard Tingle It is for a school assignment and the instructions state that both classes have to have a toString method one that displays the board, and the other on how to display each individual object.

Comment: @azurefrog , I was using that as an example and now I can see that was in poor taste, I will call it Tile.

Comment: says they have to have them but presumably not that you have to use them in this way? It's normal to have a toString method to describe an object for debug purposes.

Comment: So why dont you do it like you described? in Game.java create a toString Method, which iterates through the tiles and within each iteration call the tile's toString method. I think I dont get the problem

Comment: Can you provide the code for your `toString()` methods? It sounds like you're saying that you print strings inside the toString() method. Instead, you should be *creating* a string, which can be printed by some caller.

Comment: @Richard Tingle; Consider it like a checker/chess board, with the `Game.toString()` invoking the whole gameboard while using `Tile.toString()` to display each tile a certain way, based on those attributes.

Comment: What you describe sounds like a reasonable approach to the problem. Please add the code of your two `toString()` methods so we can see what you're trying to do.

Comment: "Is this the appropriate logic for this problem or am I doing it completely wrong?" -- Appropriate for what purpose?  Wrong in what sense?

Comment: we need to see code to know what the issue is. Each Tile object should take care of printing its own state. Game's toString should just run through the list of Tiles and append its string representation to a stringbuilder, while doing formatting.   see, now with code: don't use System.out.println in your toString, you're getting confused. use stringbuilder to create a single string and return that.

Comment: Instead of the comments, you should put the instructions of your assignment clearly in your question. It's important - you are probably not doing the correct thing if you pass a parameter to `toString` as it's overloading it and that's probably not what they meant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're mixing up two concepts: creation of a string in memory, and printing.

Your toString() method should not call `System.out.println()`. Instead, it should just be *creating* a string, which can be printed by some caller.

In addition, if you're trying to provide the conventional `toString()` method, it doesn't take any arguments. Since it's an instance method, it has access to the object's fields.

```
public class Game {
  private int rows, columns;
  private int tileArr[][];

  ...

  public String toString(){
      StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
      for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++){      
         for(int j = 0; j < columns; j++){ 
            builder.append( tileArr[i][j].toString() );
            builder.append(" "); // If tiles need to be separated.
         }   
         builder.append("\n");
      }
      return builder.toString();
   }
}
```